# Steps to access Django application hosted in VM from Windows 7 client

Tags: django, wxpython, sql-server-2008-r2, vmware, python-2.7

We have developed an application using DJango 1.3.1, Python 2.7.2 using Database as SQL server 2008.  All these are hosted in Win 2008 R2 operating system on VM.  The clients has windows 7 as o/s.

We developed application keeping in view with out VM, all of sudden client has come back saying they can only host the application on VM. Now the challnege is to access application from client to server which is on VM.

If anyone has done this kind of applications, request them share step to access the applicaiton on VM.

As I am good at standalone systems, not having knowledge on VM accessbility.

We have done all project and waiting to someone to respond ASAP.

Thanks in advance for your guidence.

Regards,
Shiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help you a bit, although my set-up is slightly different. I am running an ASP.NET web app developed on Windows7 via VMware fusion on OS X. I access the web app from outside the VM (browser of Mac or other computers/phones within the network).

Here are the needed settings:

- Network adapter set to (Bridged), so that the VM has its own IP address
- Configure the VM to have a static IP

At this point, the VM is acting as its own machine, so you can access it as if it were another server sitting on the network.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between VMs and traditional machines *that should affect your application*. As far as your code is concerned, it doesn't care if its being installed on a regular machine or a virtualized guest.

The only consideration (as pointed to by @Brett) is networking.

If the goal is that *only* the host will access the guest, then you need to setup a "host only" adapter. If your app is being run via VMWare Workstation (the desktop product), see [this support document](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_advanced_ipaddress.html) from vmware.

If the application is going to be deployed on vmware's infrastructure products like EXSi, then the process is simpler. You simply assign the network adapter the correct IP in the virtual machine itself - as if there was no virtualization.

You have tagged your question with wxpython. If you need remote desktop access - you can enable remote desktop on your guest (Windows Server), and access the app from Windows 7 from RDC.

Comment: Thanks Brett and Burhan for your prompt and valuable guidance.  In the mean time I will discuss with my clinet network people to get more on VM info and as you both suggested request them to do needful as well.

Comment: You should pick an answer and mark the question as answered. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)